# How do I get full divs throughout scrolling in the overflow?

Tags: css

I have an `absolute` positioned div combined with some floated divs underneath.  How can I make the orange and the blue divs full height throughout the scroll no matter how big or small the absolute positioned div gets, using only CSS?

**Edit** because it may have not been clear, the absolute positioned div is dynamic in height and I won't know that ahead of time.  The height was set for demo purposes.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}

.block2 {
  width: 120px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  width: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='block block1'>block1</div>
    <div class='block block2'>block2</div>
    <div class='overlay'></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that the `.overlay` is `absolute`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to not set an explicit height on the `container` and set the `block` height to `100%`.

```
block, container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I won't know the height ahead of time and it's dynamic.

Comment: Don't set a height on the `.container` - see my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using only CSS, the most dynamic you're going to make the height of the blue and orange boxes is by giving them a height of 100%. Even that will give you a maximum height of their containing element (`container`). The only way you are going to make the height of the blue and orange boxes equal the height of the absolute member is by giving the blue and orange boxes the same height magnitude (`500px`) as the absolute member.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}

.block2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 500px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  width: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='block block1'>block1</div>
    <div class='block block2'>block2</div>
    <div class='overlay'></div>
  </div>
```

If the height of the absolute member is going to be dynamically modified (in any case), then without a CSS preprocessor, using JQuery or Javascript would be an easy alternative. However, you have stated that you are only are worried about CSS, so I am making the assumption that the absolute positioned element will stay a static height of 500px.

Comment: I won't know the height ahead of time and it's dynamic.